# Integrate amazon AWS with yii 2.0

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, yii2, aws-sdk

How do I integrate my Yii 2.0 project with Aws ?
I have installed it using composer

```
"aws/aws-sdk-php": "2.*",
```

and included the

```
require '../vendor/aws/aws-autoloader.php';
```

But when I try to instantiate my S3 client, it keeps telling me that Aws does not exist.

Answer (score 2):

You can refer the following link on github

https://github.com/JDpawar/yii2-aws-s3-sdk

It has the exact details how to use the S3 SDK along with the Yii 2 App.

Comment: Link only answers are not welcomed on Stack Overflow. It will be better if you add some information.

Answer (score 1):

## AWS SDK for Yii2 - Use Amazon Web Services in your Yii2 project

This extension provides the AWS SDK 3 integration for the Yii2 framework

### Installation

The preferred way to install this extension is through [composer](http://getcomposer.org/download/).

Either run

> php composer.phar require --prefer-dist fedemotta/yii2-aws-sdk "*"

or add

> "fedemotta/yii2-aws-sdk": "*"

to the require section of your `composer.json` file.

> Note: You can still use AWS version 2 if you specify fedemotta/yii2-aws-sdk "1.*"

### Usage

To use this extension, simply add the following code in your application configuration:

```
<?php
return [
//....
'components' => [
    'awssdk' => [
        'class' => 'fedemotta\awssdk\AwsSdk',
        'credentials' => [ //you can use a different method to grant access
            'key' => 'your-aws-key',
            'secret' => 'your-aws-secret',
        ],
        'region' => 'your-aws-region', //i.e.: 'us-east-1'
        'version' => 'your-aws-version', //i.e.: 'latest'
    ],
],
];
?>
```

Getting all balancer names from AWS:

```
<?php
$aws = Yii::$app->awssdk->getAwsSdk();
$elb = $aws->createElasticloadbalancing();
$load_balancers = $elb->describeLoadBalancers()->toArray();
if (isset($load_balancers['LoadBalancerDescriptions'])){
    foreach ($load_balancers['LoadBalancerDescriptions'] as $balancer){
        if (isset($balancer['LoadBalancerName'])){ 
            echo $balancer['LoadBalancerName'];
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Download an object from S3:

```
<?php
//specify the region if it is different than the main configuration region
Yii::$app->awssdk->region = 'sa-east-1';
$aws = Yii::$app->awssdk->getAwsSdk();
//use s3
$s3 = $aws->createS3();
$result = $s3->listObjects(['Bucket' => 'your-bucket-id',
                            "Prefix" =>   "your-path"])->toArray();
//get the last object from s3
$object = end($result['Contents']);
$key = $object['Key'];
$file = $s3->getObject([
'Bucket' => 'your-bucket-id',
'Key' => $key
]);
//download the file
header('Content-Type: ' . $file['ContentType']);
echo $file['Body'];
?>
```

Comment: Link only answers are not welcomed on Stack Overflow. It will be better if you add some information.

Comment: Edited answer above. Thank you for your comments.

Comment: your answer makes no sense. why get the load balancer ? The guy wants to know how to upload, view and delete file on S3

Comment: The guy wants to integrate Amazon AWS with yii2. AWS SDK for Yii2 provides this integration. Where it says that he want to upload, view and delete files? It was just an example of use.

Comment: the "...But when I try to instantiate my S3 client, it keeps telling me that AWS does not exist...." part. However, I believe your answer solves the issue of OP being unable to interact with the imported library.

Answer (score 1):

Run the Composer command to install s3 extension. composer require frostealth/yii2-aws-s3 ~1.0@stable

```
Open common/config/main.php file and add below code into "components" section. "s3bucket" => [ "class" => \frostealth\yii2\aws\s3\Storage::className(), "region" => "Your region", "credentials" => [ "key" => "your aws s3 key", "secret" => "your aws s3 secret", ], "bucket" => "your aws s3 bucket", "defaultAcl" => \frostealth\yii2\aws\s3\Storage::ACL_PUBLIC_READ, "debug" => false, // bool|array ],

Use below code to upload image on s3 $s3 = Yii::$app->get('s3bucket')->upload('upload image name', 'path of local folder where image located');

After uploading you get status code and image url. you can get like below $status = $s3["@metadata"]["statusCode"]; $imageUrl = $s3["@metadata"]["effectiveUri"];
```

Answer (score 0):

I reimport my extension using composer,
and adding

```
require (\Yii::getAlias('@vendor/autoload.php'));
```

Somehow I got it working by adding 'autoload' in json composer

```
"autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "vendor\\aws\\" :""
        }
    }
```

and then run

```
php composer.phar dumpautoload
```

Answer (score 0):

Was looking around for this for a few hours and only found other packages to solve the issue. Wanted to implement the AWS package directly. So from

Installed the latest aws-sdk via composer.

I am using
`"aws/aws-sdk-php": "^3.259"`

Make sure aws source and location is correct in the vendor/composer/autoload_psr4.php
`'Aws\\' => array($vendorDir . '/aws/aws-sdk-php/src')`

After that ran composer update as mentioned by @Karate_Dog

```
    php composer.phar dumpautoload
```